How LSTM works for dataset by the shape (batch_size, num_word, dim)?
You have a batch of sentences that each sentence can be represented by the shape (num_word, dim) You feed dataset shape=(batch_size, num_word, dim) into an LSTM layer. Please Explain how the output of this layer is calculated? How is parallelization? What is return_sequences=True in keras LSTM layer?
what i think
If the batch contains three-word sentences with dim=5:
word-1=[v11, v12, v13, v14, v15]
word-2=[v21, v22, v23, v24, v25]
word-3=[v31, v32, v33, v34, v35]

In this case, the lstm output is calculated as follows:
NOTE: I skip the complicated LSTM cell calculations and just multiply the vectors by the weights.
weight=[w1, w2, w3, w4, w5]

step-1:
word_1 * weight
= [v11, v12, v13, v14, v15] * [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5] = [v11 * w1, v12 * w2, v13 * w3, v14 * w4, v15 * w5]
= [s11, s12, s13, s14, s15]
= S1

step-2:
(S1 + word_2) * weight = ... = S2

step-3:
(S2 + word_3) * weight = ... = S3

The output from the last cell is S3.
As you can see, in step-2 (cell-2), the output S2 has only the information of the first two words.
The output of the step-1 (cell-1) has only the information of the first word.
So can it be said that return_sequences=True in keras returns the following value: [S1, S2, S3]?
Is multiplication correct? And is it possible to parallelize LSTM like Attention?
